# If request object is not being used should i remove it from parameter of callback

Tags: node.js, api, express

If request object is not being used inside api callback function should i remove it from parameters of callback. I think it does not make a difference but i am curious what is the practice.

```
app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  res.send('hello world')
})
```

The req in params of callback function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It does make a difference.

If you were to remove that first parameter, then this code would not longer work, you would get an error like

`res.send is not a function`.

That's because the express `.get` method is going to insert the request object as the first parameter, and the response object as the second paremeter.

If you were to remove 'req' as the first parameter, the request object would still be passed as the first parameter. There's no stopping express from doing that.

As a convention, if for example ESLint is giving you issues re: unused-vars, you can prefix unused first parameters with an underscore, like `_res`.

Now if you're talking about subsuqent parameters on the otherhand, it's fine to leave them off, which is in fact what you're doing here, you can see from the [express documentation](https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#middleware-callback-function-examples) that the callback also accepts a third argument, `next`, which you're not declaring or using here.

Comment: Actually it was the VSCode fading out unused variables but your point about underscore solves that too Thanks for the detailed explanation.